# Is there a one-stop shop to introduce businesses to accepting Bitcoin?

Tags: business

I'd like to promote Bitcoin in my neighborhood, but I'd also like to do it efficiently... So I'm trying to figure out where and how to direct business owners into a simple A-B-C set of steps that explains everything from the hardware / software to the tax implications / software needed.

I know there exist lists of tools businesses could use, but those lists often seem overwhelming. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I just set up a very website that shows people how they can earn Bitcoins, it's simply called [Earn Bitcoins](http://earn-bitcoins.com/index.html).

Under the [downloads](http://earn-bitcoins.com/downloads.html) section there is a free, easy to use PDF guide that shows brick and mortar shops the advantages of accepting Bitcoins and how they can easily integrate it. Please feel free to use it. I will also publish a print version. The one that's included there right now is better suitable for on-screen reading.

I also run [Bitbond.net](https://www.bitbond.net/) with my co-founder. We want to use the flyer to spread the word in small shops in Berlin. The plan is simply to walk into shops, show them the flyer and explain them why and how it's good for them to accept Bitcoins. Check out the doc and let me know what you think. :)

Comment: I'd still like to see instructions that address (at least for US businesses) the tax implications of using Bitcoin. I see that as the greatest hurdle to getting them on board: incorporating Bitcoin into their current tax receipt system.

Comment: It's definitely an important step to cover such topics. In Germany for instance Bitcoin is treated as a foreign currency. So when we have Euros as our home currency and someone accepts Bitcoins, it's as if they accepted any other foreign currency in cash. You have to convert it at the current exchange rate in your accounting and pay your taxes based on that income. However, I don't know if such a treatment would also apply to US businesses. It depends on the regulatory classification of Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not been on the receiving-end of person-to-business bitcoin purchases, I have had many run-ins with bitpay.com. https://bitpay.com/tour The best part in my opinion is, as far as I understand their business model, using them to accept bitcoin requires little to no knowledge of or interaction with bitcoin. Instead, you integrate them with your website or PoS and they handle the transactions and send you fiat currency.

Their homepage includes images of major companies/applications currently using them in some capacity. At the time of this writing, that is: Microsoft, Neteller, Virgin Wireless, Shopify, Zynga, Newegg.